# Extra line draining into P-Trap in bathroom sink is leaking

Tags: plumbing, leak, sink

In my upstairs bathroom sink there's an extra line that feeds in from the wall to the drain pipe, directly above the P-Trap. I keep looking at different diagrams but none of them include this line to explain what it's possibly there for. Any ideas what this might be?

[image]

I'm assuming the best course of action is going to be to remove the P-trap first and see what that tells me, but I'd like to know a little more about what's actually going on here and why I have this extra line that nobody else does.

Edit: I'm now fairly confident that it's the A/C Condensate drain line. Here's a shot of the back of the line with the clamp loosened.

[image: condensate line]

Comment: What is on the other side of that wall?  It is a drain line for something.  Try to tighten the clamp with a screwdriver.

Comment: There's a stairwell on the other side of the wall. I'm thinking now it might be a drain line from the A/C unit in the attic.

Comment: Either the clamp is loose or the rubber hose has a leak.  If the rubber hose, then a few bucks for new hose and clamps and maybe a screwdriver/nut driver is all you need for repair/fix, but that top clamp seems/looks loose.

Comment: I removed the P-Trap, cleaned out the horrible sludge and saw that the open drain pipe and the point of the clamp were both continuing to slow drip. I tightened the clamp which did seem loose and no change either. Will remove the hose and see if it's damaged or somehow blocked internally.

Comment: what does the end of the white pipe coming from the wall look like?  it is barbed?  the a/c person probably just used a dishwasher tail-piece to dump the condensate.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger Added another picture of the underside of the line. Looks like the tube is not attached great at the bottom. Unfortunately I'm both unable to remove it easily or push it further on. It appears to be stuck extremely tight and the PVC drain behind it is not in any way solid.

Comment: I'd just get a new hose and cut it nice and square and make it a little long so it pushes back on the pipe coming out of the wall.  probably 7/8" ID rubber hose is what that is but you can measure the ID.  I've also used a heat gun to get vinyl tubing to open enough to get it onto barbed fittings - maybe that would work on rubber too.  you should be able to get a pair of vice grips on the pipe before the fitting so you are pulling the stub while pushing the rubber pipe onto it when re-installing.

Comment: That's a threaded adapter, which is an incorrect type to clamp a hose to.  You can either cut that adapter off and glue a reducer (to which you can clamp your hose) on, or get a female-threaded adapter and/or reducer to which you can clamp the hose.

Comment: @Huesmann Yeah, I think you're right. I replaced the hose with one I cut better but there's still an incredibly slow drip coming through. I'm not comfortable in my PVC cutting/gluing abilities, so the problem I've got is that threaded part is 3/4" inch and I want a 3/4" smooth part to slide the hose on, but I'm not sure what part that'd even be since a normal reducer would go from 1" down to 3/4".
Since it's not connecting to more PVC I'm wondering if Teflon tape might improve the seal too.

Comment: Yes, even though you clamp the hose on tightly, with threads it's probably impossible to totally seal the rubber down to the "valleys" of the threads (if that makes sense).  You need a smooth surface to get good rubber contact/seal.  If you don't want to fuss with it too much, perhaps you could use some silicone sealant to basically smooth out the threads—smear some on there and smooth it out so that you have a better surface to clamp the hose to.

Comment: I pulled it off last night and finally realized that the stem where the right end of the hose connects to the drain was about 95% blocked with gunk and so the condensation was backing up in the line and making it's way out between the threads. I cleaned that part out, and added some tape along the threads reattached everything and haven't had a drip in over 12 hours. Think we're all good. Thanks for the advice!